# How can I delete all of the contents of a directory (including subdirectories) except one subdirectory?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write an automated build and deploy script using PowerShell 2 for my angular2 app, but seeing as how our ASP.NET Web API lives in `api/`, I want to delete all of the old angular code without touching the API.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path  $destination -Recurse -exclude somefile.txt |
Select -ExpandProperty FullName |
Where {$_ -notlike $destination+'\api*'} |
sort length -Descending |
Remove-Item -force -recurse
```

`$destination` is the directory where the app gets installed.

Quick folder tree in case I wasn't clear above:

```
$destination
    api\
    app\
    assets\
    vendor\
    index.html
    main.js
    system-config.js
```

As above, I want to delete everything but `api\`

Answer (score 5):

I don’t have access to PowerShell 2.  But, using PowerShell 3 (and later versions), you should be able to simplify your code by using something like this:

```
$path = "C:\test path"
Remove-Item $path -recurse -Exclude "api"
```

I created the same folder structure you specified assuming that *api*, *app*, *assets*, and *vendor* are sub-folders.  I ran the script in the PowerShell IDE and it removed everything under the test path except for the api folder.  I would assume that PowerShell 2 supports the same parameters on the command.